# Long path fails to load with react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a VerifyEmail route that takes on a JWT token as a parameter. However, it does not load. Is there anyway to get it to load? The route loads if the token is short, about 10 characters long. Anything longer it does not work. I was wondering if there's a limit to the length of the url path for react-router-dom to be causing this problem.

In my App.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./components/Home"
import Login from "./components/Login"
import Logout from "./components/Logout"
import SignUp from "./components/SignUp"
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar"
import VerifyEmail from "./features/users/VerifyEmail"
import { selectCurrentToken } from './features/auth/authSlice'
import { useSelector } from "react-redux/es/hooks/useSelector";

function App() {
  const auth = useSelector(selectCurrentToken)

  return (
    <>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Navbar auth={auth} />
        <Routes>
          <Route index element={<Home />} />
          {!auth && <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />}
          {auth && <Route path="/logout" element={<Logout />} />}
          <Route path="/signup" element={<SignUp />} />
          <Route path="/verify/:token" element={<VerifyEmail />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

In my VerifyEmail.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'

const VerifyEmail = () => {
  const { token } = useParams()

  return (
    <div>{token}</div>
  )
}

export default VerifyEmail
```

When I try this link, I get a bad request.

http://localhost:5173/verify/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6ImUiLCJpYXQiOjE2OTE1NDkwMjcsImV4cCI6MTY5MTU3MDYyN30.HqPtksRbGTxxP8EeFs7XLHfHQLBXleaVil6MYmiKB3Y

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhuzb.png)

Comment: No, not really. It's more likely the token value contains an invalid URL path value. Can you [edit] to share an [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with and an example path you are trying to match? It might just be easier to pass the token value as a query parameter.

Comment: I edited my question. What do you mean by passing token value as a query parameter?

Comment: I mean something like `"/verify?token=jssdlfksdklserdf"`. If you like, I can answer to provide a solution for this. That said, I've copy/pasted your code into a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/long-path-fails-to-load-with-react-router-dom-rcrjkc) and a link with that exact token is matched in the route just fine. I can't reproduce any issue you describe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web server is misinterpret your jwt with a file. How is it know the difference between `locahost:5173/favicon.ico` and `localhost:5173/U3MDYyN30.HqPtksRbGTxxP8EeFs7`. So it will throw an error `Not Found` as you show in the image. You have two options to handle this:

1. If you are using webpack, you can config to disable the dot rule ([docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverhistoryapifallback)).

```
 historyApiFallback: {
    disableDotRule: true
 }
```

2. You can modify the route and pass the JWT as a query parameter

```
<Route path="/verify" element={<VerifyEmail />} />
```

And in your VerifyEmail component, use useQuery to get the value of token

```
// http://localhost:5173/verify?token=abcxyx
import { useQuery } from 'react-router-dom';

function VerifyEmail() {
   let query = useQuery();
   let token = query.get('token');

   // Rest of your component logic
}
```

Comment: You likely meant [useSearchParams](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-search-params) since `react-router-dom` doesn't export a `useQuery` hook.